# null cannot be cast to non-null on NavHostFragment inside MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I tried to run an outdated application. I had to upgrade gradle files, dependencies, kotlin version, switch from synthetic files to viewbinding.

I did all that and then I got an error, saying, "Error inflating class fragment" inside the MainActivity file. So I changed fragment to FrameLayout inside the activity_main.xml file.

But now I have an error, saying: "java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment".

Please take a look at both full error messages, the ActivityMain.kt file, and the activity_main.xml file. I've tried a lot of answers on the internet but nothing helped. I am a bit out of options to think of.

Thank you!

There seems to be a problem I think in the ActivityMain.kt file and the activity_main.xml file. I don't know what though. Here are some photos!

[image: error one ('Error inflating class fragment')]

[image: error 2 ('java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment')]

acitivty_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.activities.main.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/textColorPrimaryInverse"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:titleTextColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBar"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header_layout"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_color"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```
MainActivity.Kt File


package com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.activities.main

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.*
import com.gullygarms.app.gullygarms.R
import com.gullygarms.app.gullygarms.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.gullygarms.app.gullygarms.databinding.DrawerHeaderLayoutBinding
import com.gullygarms.app.gullygarms.utils.MApplication
import com.gullygarms.gullygarms.model.UserModel
import com.gullygarms.gullygarms.utils.FirestoreUtil
import com.gullygarms.gullygarms.utils.FirestoreUtil.auth
import com.gullygarms.gullygarms.utils.Prefs
import com.kaopiz.kprogresshud.KProgressHUD

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var hud: KProgressHUD
    private lateinit var alertDialog: AlertDialog
    private lateinit var builder: AlertDialog.Builder
    private lateinit var userModel: UserModel
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var token = ""
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    lateinit var navViewHeaderLayoutBinding: DrawerHeaderLayoutBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)

        obtainUserToken()
        navViewHeaderLayoutBinding =
            DrawerHeaderLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, binding.navView, true)
        val navHost =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragment) as NavHostFragment

        navController = navHost.navController
        val navInflater = navController.navInflater
        val navGraph = navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.main_nav)
        if (Prefs.getInstance(this)!!.hasCompletedWalkthrough) {
            if (auth.currentUser == null) {
                navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.authFragment)
            } else {
                navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.homeFragment)
                FirestoreUtil.getCurrentUser({
                    userModel = it.toObject(UserModel::class.java)!!
                    userModel.fcmToken = token
                    navViewHeaderLayoutBinding.user = userModel
                    MApplication.currentUser = userModel
                    MApplication.currentUser!!.active = true
                    FirestoreUtil.updateUser(MApplication.currentUser!!) {
                    }
                }, {
                    navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.authFragment)
                })
            }
        } else {
            navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.onBoardingFragment)
        }
        navController.graph = navGraph
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if (destination.id == R.id.homeFragment ||
                destination.id == R.id.shopFragment ||
                destination.id == R.id.bagFragment ||
                destination.id == R.id.searchFragment ||
                destination.id == R.id.ordersFragment ||
                destination.id == R.id.wishListFragment ||
                destination.id == R.id.profileFragment
            ) {
                binding.drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
            } else {
                binding.drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
            }

            if (destination.id == R.id.onBoardingFragment ||
                destination.id == R.id.authFragment ||
                destination.id == R.id.loginFragment ||
                destination.id == R.id.signUpFragment
//                destination.id == R.id.fullScreenImageViewer ||
//                destination.id == R.id.videoFragment
            ) {
                binding.appBar.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                binding.appBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolBar)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(binding.navView.menu, binding.drawerLayout)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.homeFragment -> {
                    if (navController.currentDestination?.id != R.id.homeFragment) {
                        navController.navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
                    }
                    true
                }
                R.id.shopFragment -> {
                    if (navController.currentDestination?.id != R.id.shopFragment) {
                        navController.navigate(R.id.shopFragment)
                    }
                    true
                }
                R.id.bagFragment -> {
                    if (navController.currentDestination?.id != R.id.bagFragment) {
                        navController.navigate(R.id.bagFragment)
                    }
                    true
                }
                R.id.searchFragment -> {
                    if (navController.currentDestination?.id != R.id.searchFragment) {
                        navController.navigate(R.id.searchFragment)
                    }
                    true
                }
                R.id.ordersFragment -> {
                    if (navController.currentDestination?.id != R.id.ordersFragment) {
                        navController.navigate(R.id.ordersFragment)
                    }
                    true
                }
                R.id.wishListFragment -> {
                    if (navController.currentDestination?.id != R.id.wishListFragment) {
                        navController.navigate(R.id.wishListFragment)
                    }
                    true
                }

                R.id.profileFragment -> {
                    if (navController.currentDestination?.id != R.id.profileFragment) {
                        navController.navigate(R.id.profileFragment)
                    }
                    true
                }
                R.id.logout -> {
                    MApplication.currentUser!!.active = false
                    FirestoreUtil.updateUser(MApplication.currentUser!!) {
                        auth.signOut()
                        MApplication.currentUser = null
                        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                        finish()
                    }
                    true
                }

                else -> false
            }
        }
        prepareDialogs()

    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) =
        item.onNavDestinationSelected(findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment))
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() =
        findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)

    private fun prepareDialogs() {
        hud = KProgressHUD.create(this)
            .setStyle(KProgressHUD.Style.SPIN_INDETERMINATE)
            .setDimAmount(0.6f)
            .setCancellable(false)
            .setMaxProgress(100)
    }

    fun showDialog(message: String) {
        builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setMessage(message)
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok") { _, _ -> }
        alertDialog = builder.create()
        alertDialog.show()
    }

    fun showProgress(message: String) {
        hud.setLabel(message)
        hud.show()
    }

    fun hideProgress() {
        hud.dismiss()
    }

    fun checkPermissions(code: Int): Boolean {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val read =
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            val write =
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            val camera =
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            return if (!read || !write || !camera) {
                requestPermissions(
                    arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                    ), code
                )
                false
            } else {
                true
            }
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    private fun obtainUserToken() {
        FirestoreUtil.getUserToken {
            if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                token = it
            }
        }
    }

    fun isDarkTheme(): Boolean {
        return this.resources.configuration.uiMode and
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        MApplication.ephemeralKeyProvider.destroy()
    }
}
```

main_nav.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/onBoardingFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/onBoardingFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.onBoarding.OnBoardingFragment"
        android:label="@string/on_boarding"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_on_boarding">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_onBoardingFragment_to_authFragment"
            app:destination="@id/authFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/authFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.auth.AuthFragment"
        android:label="@string/auth"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_auth">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_authFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_authFragment_to_signUpFragment"
            app:destination="@id/signUpFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/signUpFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.signup.SignUpFragment"
        android:label="@string/sign_up"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sign_up" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.login.LoginFragment"
        android:label="@string/log_in"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_productDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/productDetailsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_bagFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bagFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bagFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.bag.BagFragment"
        android:label="@string/bag"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bag">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_bagFragment_to_checkoutFragment"
            app:destination="@id/checkoutFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ordersFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.orders.OrdersFragment"
        android:label="@string/orders"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_orders">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_ordersFragment_to_bagFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bagFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/settingsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_profileDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileDetailsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_contactUsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/contactUsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_ordersFragment"
            app:destination="@id/ordersFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_wishListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/wishListFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.search.SearchFragment"
        android:label="@string/search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_searchFragment_to_productDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/productDetailsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/shopFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.shop.ShopFragment"
        android:label="@string/shop"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_shop">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_shopFragment_to_shopDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/shopDetailsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/wishListFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.wishList.WishListFragment"
        android:label="@string/wish_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_wish_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_wishListFragment_to_productDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/productDetailsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/productDetailsFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.productDetails.ProductDetailsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_product_details">
        <argument
            android:name="product"
            app:argType="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.model.ProductModel" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/shopDetailsFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.shopDetails.ShopDetailsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_shop_details">
        <argument
            android:name="id"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="name"
            app:argType="string" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_shopDetailsFragment_to_productDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/productDetailsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/contactUsFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.contactUs.ContactUsFragment"
        android:label="@string/contact_us"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_contact_us" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileDetailsFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.profileDetails.ProfileDetailsFragment"
        android:label="@string/account_details"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile_details" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.settings.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/checkoutFragment"
        android:name="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.ui.fragments.checkout.CheckoutFragment"
        android:label="@string/checkout"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_checkout">
        <argument
            android:name="products"
            app:argType="com.gullygarms.gullygarms.model.ProductModel[]" />
        <argument
            android:name="total"
            app:argType="string" />

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: post your main_nav.xml

Comment: as I see, you set app:startDestination to onBoardingFragment but when the activity is created, it checks what fragment should be created, and it could be other than onBoardingFragment. What I could do is create some MainFragment and set it as start destination and it's his responsibility to check which fragment to display. it's just a first guess.. :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting, so it would basically just be an empty MainFragment. I'll give it a try, thanks @Walid

Comment: yes, its only responsibility is to decide which fragment to create. So it would be something like this:
MainActivity -> MainFragment -> WhateverFragment..

Comment: I've tried to add this but I still get the same errors with a MainFragment. So with FrameLayout I get: ""java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment". And with FragmentContainerView I get: "Error inflating class fragment".

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I believe the `FrameLayout` needs to be a `FragmentContainerView`.

As far as I know you can't define fragments in xml by using a `FrameLayout`. `FragmentContainerView` exists for exactly this purpose. see https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView

Comment: Thanks for your answer @IvoBeckers. I've changed it to FragmentContainerView. And now I get the good old "Error inflating class fragment" error. I am an iOS developer that just started using android studio, so I am not that familiar.